# how to disable cloudformation stack rollback for the stacks created by stackset

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a CloudFormation StackSet question. Is it possible to disable rollback for the stacks created by the StackSet?

For creating individual stack we have that option, but didn't find that option for stackset. Please advise.